# Can you stop this material from breaking?

Tags: mesh, rigging

Before rigged I think it looks ok
[image: Before Rigged]

After rigged, body breaks a bit at the bottom but clothes are still ok except when moving them with the body
[image: After Rigged]

In Second Life Viewer, patchy when avatar moved and issues at seems and underneath
[image: In Second Life]

I'm wondering in general if there is a way to fix this, or if anybody is experienced and could make a simple design I have for a mesh body work

Comment: Seems like you just need to mess with the Weight painting per bone to even things out a bit, the automatic weights didn't capture everything correctly.

Comment: I literally do not know how to mess around with the weights and fix it myself

Comment: As with  most things in Blender there are [tons of resources](https://www.google.com/search?q=blender+weight+painting).